# Why not GIL put little infuence on IO intensive multi threads

Tags: python, gil

I have known that GIL affects multi threads when the thread execute CPU intensive task and it can not take advantage of multi cores.

But I feel very confused that it works well when the thread execute IO intensive task.I guess that the thread will release GIL when it is blocked.It's right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess that the thread will release GIL when it is blocked.

Yes, exactly.

Principally, that's all needed in an answer :)

Comment: Thanks, you are humorful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, IO operations typically release the GIL.